# Why do all the vectors in my loop get rotated in this processing code

Tags: processing

I have a bug in a simple code which I am building. The code grows lines from nodes. Each node is two points and a line connecting the two. Each node can grow once and growth is handled in a growth function

Part of growth function of the node class has a conditional that rotates the direction of the node (so the lines are slightly wavy) and for some reason all of the nodes get rotated in the way I have written the code. Can someone point out the undoubtedly simple error I have made?

Code:

```java
Node[] ns;
int nodeCount;

void setup() {
size(1024, 1024, P3D); 
background(255);
stroke(0);
frameRate(60);
fill(0);
nodeCount = int(10000);
ns = new Node[nodeCount];

for(int i = 0; i < nodeCount; i++){
ns[i] = new Node(i, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, new PVector(0, 0), false, false, false);
}  

for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
ns[i] = new Node(i, random(float(width)), random(float(height)), 5, 0, random(100), new PVector(10, 10).rotate(random(-PI/2, PI/2)), true, false, true);
}
}

void draw() {
background(255);

//print("frame ");
for ( Node n: ns ){

if ( n.Active ) {
//print(n.index, " ");
n.display();
if ( n.Growth ){
n.grow();
}
}
if( n.Init ){
n.init(); 
}

}
}

class Node {
int index;
float xi, yi, size, theta, noiseoff;
PVector dir;
Boolean Active, Growth, Init;
Node(int ind, float x, float y, float s, float t, float n, PVector d, Boolean A, Boolean G, Boolean I) {
index = ind;
xi = x;
yi = y;
size = s;
theta = t;
noiseoff = n;
dir = d;
Active = A;
Growth = G;
Init = I;
}

void display(){

strokeWeight(0);
ellipse(xi, yi, size, size);
ellipse(xi + dir.x, yi + dir.y, size, size);
strokeWeight(size);
line(xi, yi, xi + dir.x, yi + dir.y);

//xi = xi + dir.x;
//yi = yi + dir.y;

}

void grow(){
boolean done = false;
int i = index + 1;
PVector tempDir = new PVector(0, 0);

tempDir = dir;

while ( !done & i < nodeCount & Growth ) {

if ( ns[i].Active == false ) {

if( random(100) > 85 ){
noiseoff += 0.01;
theta = map(noise(noiseoff), 0, 1, -PI/12, PI/12);
tempDir.rotate(theta);
}

ns[i] = new Node(i, xi + tempDir.x, yi + tempDir.y, size, theta, noiseoff, tempDir, true, false, true);
Growth = false;
done = true;
if (i == nodeCount - 1 ) {
 done = true; 
}
}
i++;
if (i == nodeCount ) {
 done = true; 
}
} 
i++;  
}

void init(){
Growth = true;
Init = false;
}
}
```

Another version that introduces createNode() method to remove the loop over the node array within the node class (still has the bug):

```
Node[] ns;
int nodeCount;


void setup() {
size(1024, 1024, P3D); 
background(255);
stroke(0);
frameRate(60);
fill(0);
nodeCount = int(10000);
ns = new Node[nodeCount];


// Initialize array with blank nodes 
for(int i = 0; i < nodeCount; i++){
ns[i] = new Node(i, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, new PVector(0, 0), false, false, false);
}  

// Create Root node
createNode(random(float(width)), random(float(height)), 5, 0, random(100), new PVector(2.5, 2.5).rotate(random(-PI/2, PI/2)), true, false, true);

}



void draw() {
background(255);



for ( Node n: ns ){

if ( n.Active ) {
// Draw active nodes
n.display();
// Grow nodes which haven't grown before
if ( n.Growth ){
n.grow();
}
}
// Initialize nodes which were grown last time step (so that they can grown in the subsequent timestep)
if( n.Init ){
n.init(); 
}

}
}


// Wrapper function that looks for a free row in the node array to create a new node
void createNode(float x, float y, float s, float t, float n, PVector d, Boolean A, Boolean G, Boolean I){
float xi, yi, size, theta, noiseoff;
PVector dir;
Boolean Active, Growth, Init, done;
int i;
xi = x;
yi = y;
size = s;
theta = t;
noiseoff = n;
dir = d;
Active = A;
Growth = G;
Init = I;

i = 0;
done = false;

 while ( !done ) {

 if ( ns[i].Active == false ) {
 ns[i] = new Node(i, xi + dir.x, yi + dir.y, size, theta, noiseoff, dir, true, false, true);
 done = true;
 if (i == nodeCount - 1 ) {
  done = true; 
 }
 }
 i++;
 if (i == nodeCount ) {
  done = true; 
 }
 }

}

// Node class
class Node {
int index;
float xi, yi, size, theta, noiseoff;
PVector dir;
Boolean Active, Growth, Init;
Node(int ind, float x, float y, float s, float t, float n, PVector d, Boolean A, Boolean G, Boolean I) {
index = ind;
xi = x;
yi = y;
size = s;
theta = t;
noiseoff = n;
dir = d;
Active = A;
Growth = G;
Init = I;
}


void display(){
// Draw node as two circles and a line
strokeWeight(0);
ellipse(xi, yi, size, size);
ellipse(xi + dir.x, yi + dir.y, size, size);
strokeWeight(size);
line(xi, yi, xi + dir.x, yi + dir.y);

}


// Grow method
void grow(){

int i = index + 1;
PVector tempDir = dir;


// Small chance of angle deviation
if( random(100) > 85 ){
noiseoff += 0.01;
theta = map(noise(noiseoff), 0, 1, -PI/12, PI/12);
tempDir.rotate(theta);
}

// Create new node appended onto the last
createNode(xi + tempDir.x, yi + tempDir.y, size, theta, noiseoff, tempDir, true, false, true);
// Set growth to false to prevent this node growning again
Growth = false;

}

// Initialize previously grown nodes for growth
void init(){
Growth = true;
Init = false;
}

}
```

Comment: Can you be more clear about exactly how these Nodes should behave? How should they be connected?

Comment: Sure, a node is 'born' with a magnitude (constant at this stage) and direction (random at this stage); the node is displayed as two circles and a line connecting the two in the direction/mag of the vector.

 A node can 'grow' once which *should* append onto the original node a new node with a slightly random offset angle. Once a node has grown it should never change it's properties

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was my generation of a temporary vector tempDir to rotate (as the .rotate() method rotates the vector and changes it) was slightly incorrect.

changing

```
PVector tempDir = dir;
```

to

```
PVector tempDir = new PVector(dir.x, dir.y);
```

Fixed my bug, I guess that somehow the data assignment is getting confused?

Comment: Well done on figuring it out.
```PVector tempDir = dir;``` copies the reference to that vector and therefore is not an independent PVector...it's just another variable pointing to the same object. ```PVector tempDir = new PVector(dir.x, dir.y);``` can also be written as ```PVector tempDir = dir.get();``` which will return a clone (a new object with copied x,y values)

Answer (score 0):

Your `Node#grow()` function loops through every index in the array, replacing each `Node` with a rotated version of itself.

This doesn't make a ton of sense, because you're already looping through every `Node` and calling the `grow()` function. So for every `Node`, you're looping through every `Node` and replacing it with a rotated version... why?

It looks like you're mixing logic that's supposed to operate on every `Node` with logic that operates on a single `Node`. Here's a general rule of thumb: your `Node` class should only ever deal with a single `Node`, so if you're accessing the `ns` array, something fishy is going on.

(Unless you need each `Node` to interact with every other `Node`, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.)

To fix your problem, you have to separate the logic that loops through every `Node` from the logic that modifies a single `Node`.

It might be easier if you start out with a single `Node`. Get that single `Node` working before you worry about multiple `Node` instances.

**Edit:** You're still modifying the array that holds the `Node` instances from inside every `Node`. That's the source of your confusion. I see now that you fixed your problem, but I would bet you're going to have similar issues as you continue.

Here's the example I was working on. This uses a `child` variable in each `Node` instance instead of trying to store the children in the same array that the parent `Node` instances are stored in. Maybe it'll come in handy:

```
ArrayList<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);

  for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    nodes.add(new Node());
  }
}

void mousePressed() {
  for ( Node node : nodes ) {
    node.grow();
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(255);

  for ( Node node : nodes ) {
    node.display();
  }
}

class Node {

  float x;
  float y;
  float angle;
  float length;

  Node child;

  Node() {
    x = random(width);
    y = random(height);
    angle = random(360);
    length = random(5, 10);
  }

  void display() {
    float endX = x + cos(radians(angle)) * length;
    float endY = y + sin(radians(angle)) * length;

    line(x, y, endX, endY);

    if (child != null) {
      child.display();
    }
  }

  void grow() {
    if (child == null) {
      float endX = x + cos(radians(angle)) * length;
      float endY = y + sin(radians(angle)) * length;

      child = new Node();
      child.x = endX;
      child.y = endY;
      child.angle = random(angle-10, angle+10);
    } else {
      child.grow();
    }
  }
}
```

[image: growing nodes]

Comment: The while loop in the grow function actually loops to find an empty element in the node array, it shouldn't execute any of the code unless the node's 'Active', 'Init' and 'Growth' var is set to true.

Although I am certain you are right that somehow this logic isn't working. I'm not sure how else to handle the data (the expanding list of nodes that is)

Comment: @niklz The basic lesson is this: unless you have code where the nodes interact, you shouldn't be looping through every other `Node` inside the `Node` class. Start over and get a single `Node` working, then post that code and we'll go from there.

Comment: If you comment out the call to n.grow() then it is a working single node version (although the code is somewhat pointless with one node, the most basic operation I need to have one node growing).

I guess I'll try moving the data handling part to a new function 'createNode()' which does the loop over the nodes (but this will still fail your test).

Comment: @niklz I still don't understand why you need to loop over every other `Node` inside your `Node` class. It sounds like each `Node` should have a maximum of one child. Can't you just store that in a single `Node` variable (called something like `child`) inside the `Node` class instead of looping over every other `Node`?

Comment: Edit: actually I can make the createNode function not a derivative of the node class - so win win, I'll try this thanks

Comment: Check the edit of the main question, I posted a newer version with the edit you suggested.

Comment: @niklz I see that you fixed your problem, but see my edited answer for an example of the approach I was getting at.

Comment: Thanks for your example, it is certainly a neat solution. I'm curious how the data storage works, do you not need to allocate array sizes?

Comment: @niklz I'm using the `ArrayList` class, which is like a dynamically growing array. You could also use arrays and the `append()` function, but that's less efficient.